# Not enough memory on raspberry pi to install opencv , Is there a special way to install raspbian OS on SD card to save lot free memory

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have a raspberry pi B+. I installed raspbian OS on 16GB SD card and put it in to raspberry pi(work properly). Now I want to install opencv on it. But it shows only small available memory.(cannot install opencv on it, because of not enough free space).
how can I get more memory. Is there a special way to write raspbian image  in SD card(like partition the SD card and install raspbian). looking for your help. thanx.....

Comment: Sounds fishy... 16GB SD is gigantic. I don't even get my 8GB full. Are you sure you use your whole card? If you installed a 4GB raspian image, you use only 4GB... you have to use raspi-config to enlarge your filesystem to use the full 16GB.

Comment: I'm new to raspberry pi technology. could you please tell me how to do that. Tank you very much for your help Mr.Greenflow

Comment: Just enter **sudo raspi-config** in console. First point: Expand Filesystem. Use it.

Comment: It works ... thank you very much agin, Greenflow

Answer (score 2):

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

Fresh raspian images are 2GB. If you copy such an image to a SD card, everything beyond that is unused. Fortunately this can easily be fixed.

In a console enter:

> sudo raspi-config

The menu, which appears has as first menu item:

> 1 Expand Filesystem              Ensures that all of the SD card
>   storage is available to the OS
>    1 Expand Filesystem              Ensures that all of the SD card storage is available to the OS

Use it and you are done.